# Spring Integration poller to launch Spring Batch job once when cron expression triggers

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch

We would like our Spring Batch job to fire once when the cron expression triggers every 2 minutes. But we are noticing that it runs continually when it is triggered -- as soon as the first job has completed, a second job is launched as can be seen in the logs:

```
2016-04-08 21:18:02,426 INFO [org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run() 133] - Job: [FlowJob: [name=irsDataPrepJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{subscriberReaderType=originalSubscriberReaderType, time=1460175480034}]
2016-04-08 21:18:03,095 INFO [xxx.batch.listener.IrsJobExecutionListener.beforeJob() 41] - Started jobName=[irsDataPrepJob], jobId=[99018], jobParameters={subscriberReaderType=originalSubscriberReaderType, time=1460175480034}]
2016-04-08 21:18:05,738 INFO [org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep() 146] - Executing step: [generateIrsData]
.
.
.
2016-04-08 21:18:15,264 INFO [xxx.batch.listener.IrsJobExecutionListener.afterJob() 54] - Finished jobName=[irsDataPrepJob], jobId=[99018], with status=[COMPLETED], jobParameters={subscriberReaderType=originalSubscriberReaderType, time=1460175480034}]
2016-04-08 21:18:15,929 INFO [org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run() 136] - Job: [FlowJob: [name=irsDataPrepJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{subscriberReaderType=originalSubscriberReaderType, time=1460175480034}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]
2016-04-08 21:18:15,933 INFO [org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler.handleMessageInternal() 155] - JobExecution: id=99282, version=2, startTime=Fri Apr 08 21:18:02 PDT 2016, endTime=Fri Apr 08 21:18:15 PDT 2016, lastUpdated=Fri Apr 08 21:18:15 PDT 2016, status=COMPLETED, exitStatus=exitCode=COMPLETED;exitDescription=, job=[JobInstance: id=99018, version=0, Job=[irsDataPrepJob]], jobParameters=[{subscriberReaderType=originalSubscriberReaderType, time=1460175480034}]
2016-04-08 21:18:17,826 INFO [org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run() 133] - Job: [FlowJob: [name=irsDataPrepJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{subscriberReaderType=originalSubscriberReaderType, time=1460175495933}]
```

We have a cron expression like this:

```
batch.job.schedule.cron.irsDataPrepJobRunner=0 0/2 * * * *
```

And our JavaConfig bean looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class IrsJobIntegration {

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext appContext;

@Bean
MessageChannel control() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="irsControl")
public ExpressionControlBusFactoryBean irsControlBus() {
    return new ExpressionControlBusFactoryBean();
}

@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "irsDataPrepJobInputChannel", poller = @Poller(cron="${batch.job.schedule.cron.irsDataPrepJobRunner}"))
public MessageSource<JobLaunchRequest> pollIrsDataPrepJob() {

    return new MessageSource<JobLaunchRequest>() {

        @Override
        public Message<JobLaunchRequest> receive() {
            return new GenericMessage<JobLaunchRequest>(requestIrsDataPrepJob());
        }

    };
}

@Transformer(inputChannel="irsDataPrepJobInputChannel",outputChannel="irsDataPrepJobOutputChannel")
public JobLaunchRequest requestIrsDataPrepJob() {
    JobParametersBuilder jobParametersBuilder = new JobParametersBuilder();
    jobParametersBuilder.addString("subscriberReaderType", "originalSubscriberReaderType").addLong("time",System.currentTimeMillis());
    return new JobLaunchRequest((Job) appContext.getBean("irsDataPrepJob"), jobParametersBuilder.toJobParameters());
}
```

The application context has the channels defined as:

```
<int:channel id="irsDataPrepJobInputChannel"/>
<int:channel id="irsDataPrepJobOutputChannel"/>
<int:channel id="irsDataPrepJobJobLaunchReplyChannel"/>
<batch-int:job-launching-gateway request-channel="irsDataPrepJobOutputChannel"
                                 reply-channel="irsDataPrepJobJobLaunchReplyChannel"/>
<int:logging-channel-adapter channel="irsDataPrepJobJobLaunchReplyChannel"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @Poller has an element called maxMessagesPerPoll. When maxMessagesPerPoll="1", that did the trick:

```
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "irsDataPrepJobInputChannel", poller = @Poller(cron="${batch.job.schedule.cron.irsDataPrepJobRunner}", maxMessagesPerPoll="1"))
public MessageSource<JobLaunchRequest> pollIrsDataPrepJob() {

    return new MessageSource<JobLaunchRequest>() {

        @Override
        public Message<JobLaunchRequest> receive() {
            return new GenericMessage<JobLaunchRequest>(requestIrsDataPrepJob());
        }

    };
}
```

Comment: Glad to see that you have figure out it yourself ! You can accept your own answer, of course